# How can I find the newest created file in a directory?

Tags: perl, last-modified

Is there an elegant way in Perl to find the newest file in a directory (newest by modification date)?

What I have so far is searching for the files I need, and for each one get it's modification time, push into an array containing the filename, modification time, then sort it.

There must be a better way.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your way is the "right" way if you need a sorted list (and not just the first, see Brian's answer for that).  If you don't fancy writing that code yourself, use [this](http://search.cpan.org/~tpaba/File-DirList-0.04/lib/File/DirList.pm)

```
use File::DirList;
my @list = File::DirList::list('.', 'M');
```

Personally I wouldn't go with the `ls -t` method - that involves forking another program and it's not portable.  Hardly what I'd call "elegant"!

---

Regarding rjray's solution hand coded solution, I'd change it slightly:

```
opendir(my $DH, $DIR) or die "Error opening $DIR: $!";
my @files = map { [ stat "$DIR/$_", $_ ] } grep(! /^\.\.?$/, readdir($DH));
closedir($DH);

sub rev_by_date { $b->[9] <=> $a->[9] }
my @sorted_files = sort rev_by_date @files;
```

After this, `@sorted_files` contains the sorted list, where the 0th element is the newest file, and each element itself contains a reference to the results of `stat`, with the  filename itself in the last element:

```
my @newest = @{$sorted_files[0]};
my $name = pop(@newest);
```

The advantage of this is that it's easier to change the sorting method later, if desired.

---

EDIT: here's an easier-to-read (but longer) version of the directory scan, which also ensures that only plain files are added to the listing:

```
my @files;
opendir(my $DH, $DIR) or die "Error opening $DIR: $!";
while (defined (my $file = readdir($DH))) {
  my $path = $DIR . '/' . $file;
  next unless (-f $path);           # ignore non-files - automatically does . and ..
  push(@files, [ stat(_), $path ]); # re-uses the stat results from '-f'
}
closedir($DH);
```

NB: the test for `defined()` on the result of `readdir()` is because a file called '0' would cause the loop to fail if you only test for `if (my $file = readdir($DH))`

Comment: Both `File::DirList` and `ls` requires installation (on Windows at least). `

Comment: If you want *newest* then use `@l = File::DirList::list('.', 'M'); say $l[0][0][13]` Note the capital M.

Comment: I wouldn't call his the "right" way. It's going to be a slug for a directory with many files.

Comment: Both `File::DirList::list` and `ls -t` return both filenames and *dirnames*.

Comment: brian - no more so that calling 'ls'.  JFS - my new Perl version excludes dirnames.

Comment: You don't want to make paths like that. Use File::Spec to help you.

Comment: Brian - these are examples of _some_ improvements on another poster's example, not a howto on "perfect" portable coding.  It would have been better to say _why_ you've changed your own example rather than just change it and delete the comments.

Answer (score 15):

You don't need to keep all of the modification times and filenames in a list, and you probably shouldn't. All you need to do is look at one file and see if it's older than the oldest you've previously seen:

```
{
    opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Could not open $dir: $!";

    my( $newest_name, $newest_time ) = ( undef, 2**31 -1 );

    while( defined( my $file = readdir( $dh ) ) ) {
        my $path = File::Spec->catfile( $dir, $file );
        next if -d $path; # skip directories, or anything else you like
        ( $newest_name, $newest_time ) = ( $file, -M _ ) if( -M $path < $newest_time );
    }

    print "Newest file is $newest_name\n";
}
```

Comment: It doesn't filter directories names.

Comment: Since `$newest_time` is automatically initialized to 0, `-M $path` can never be less. You can initialize it like this: `$newest_time = 2**31 - 1`

Comment: You've caught a real problem, but for the wrong reason. `-M` is negative when the file is modified after the program starts. I should set the newest time if it is not yet defined. $newest_time is not automatically initialized to zero: it's converted to 0 if it's undefined and I use it numerically (as in the `<` operator). You don't want to set it to some magic value either. You want to have the absence of value until you have a meaningful one. :)

Comment: There's still a bug in this code: for the first file -M _ returns some random value from the stat cache since the -M $path is not executed.

Comment: Could someone expand on @soger 's comment. I'd like to use (a modification of) this snippet, but I need it to be bug free of course. Brian, do you understand what soger is trying to say?

Comment: The code has been corrected since my comment, you can use it @BramVanroy.

Answer (score 11):

you could try using the shell's `ls` command:

```
@list = `ls -t`;
$newest = $list[0];
```

Comment: Only works on UNIX (or Windows with an ls command in, say, Cygwin), but it IS a more elegant solution.

Comment: It works on Windows (using gnuwin32 utilities). But `ls -t` returns both file and *directory* names.

Comment: This isn't elegant at all. It's just less typing. Now you need to create a new process for every directory you want to examine. Hardly pretty. :)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you know the `$DIR` you want to look in:

```
opendir(my $DH, $DIR) or die "Error opening $DIR: $!";
my %files = map { $_ => (stat("$DIR/$_"))[9] } grep(! /^\.\.?$/, readdir($DH));
closedir($DH);
my @sorted_files = sort { $files{$b} <=> $files{$a} } (keys %files);
# $sorted_files[0] is the most-recently modified. If it isn't the actual
# file-of-interest, you can iterate through @sorted_files until you find
# the interesting file(s).
```

The `grep` that wraps the `readdir` filters out the "." and ".." special files in a UNIX(-ish) filesystem.

Comment: Isn't this almost what Bonzo is saying he's doing? "searching for the files I need, and for each one get it's modification time, push into an array containing the filename, modification time, then sort it." You just change the array of tuples for a hash.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't let `ls` do the sorting for you as @Nathan suggests, then you can optimize your process by only keeping the newest modification time and associated filename seen thus far and replace it every time you find a newer file in the directory.  No need to keep any files around that you know are older than the newest one you've seen so far and certainly no need to sort them since you can detect which is the newest one while reading from the directory.

Answer (score -1):

Subject is old, but maybe someone will try it - it isn't portable (Unix-like systems only), but it's quite simple and works:

> chdir $directory or die "cannot change directory";
>
> my $newest_file = `bash -c 'ls -t | head -1'`;
>
> chomp $newest_file;
>
> print "$newest_file \n";

Comment: -1 I don't see any advantage of making this a shell script problem, especially when the proposed shell script attempts to parse the output of `ls`. Perl is well equipped to handle the problematic corner cases (file names with newlines, etc).