# How can I find the newest .pl file in a directory and all its subdirectories using Perl?

Tags: perl, path, directory, file-search, datecreated

How can I scan an entire directory's contents, including its subdirectories' contents, and find the newest `.pl` file within them using Perl?

I want to build a sorted array/list of the full file paths of all `.pl` files within a directory tree.

So, for example, if my base directory is `/home/users/cheeseconqueso/` I want to search for `.pl` files in that directory and any subdirectory within that path and then sort the `.pl` files by date.

The end result would be an array, `@pl_paths`, where `$pl_paths[0]` would be something like `/home/users/cheeseconqueso/maybe_not_newest_directory/surely_newest_file.pl`

From that result, I want to execute the file, but I think once I get the sorted array figured out, executing the file in `$pl_paths[0]`, won't be a problem.

There is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328673/how-can-i-find-the-newest-created-file-in-a-directory) question on SO that I have been trying to modify to suit my needs, but I am here now for obvious reasons.

The code I'm using to get the newest file NAME only in one directory is:

```
opendir(my $DH, $DIR) or die "Error opening $DIR: $!";
my %files = map { $_ => (stat("$DIR/$_"))[9] } grep(! /^\.\.?$/, readdir($DH));
closedir($DH);
my @sorted_files = sort { $files{$b} <=> $files{$a} } (keys %files);
print $sorted_files[0]."\n";
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File%3a%3aFind) if you want a core module for this, but I would prefer to use [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule).

To start off, we can find all of the `.pl` files under a directory with

```
use File::Find::Rule;
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file
                            ->name('*.pl')
                            ->in($directory);
```

Then let's use `map` to associate filenames with their modification times:

```
my @files_with_mtimes = map +{ name => $_, mtime => (stat $_)[9] }, @files;
```

And sort them by mtime:

```
my @sorted_files = reverse sort { $a->{mtime} <=> $b->{mtime} } 
                @files_with_mtimes;
```

And from there, the name of the newest one is in `$sorted_files[0]{name}`.

If you only want to find the top one, there's actually no need to do a complete sort, but the nicest solution I can think of involves some slightly advanced FP, so don't worry about it at all  if it looks strange to you:

```
use List::Util 'reduce';
my ($top_file) = reduce { $a->{mtime} >= $b->{mtime} ? $a : $b } 
  @files_with_mtimes;
```

Comment: I think you misread something in the question.... I'm looking for the newest file, not the biggest file

Comment: @CheeseConQueso oops! Will update that in a moment. Same idea applies though!

Comment: @Zaid it can't, the plus is there to make sure that it's *not* interpreted as a code block; it's a hashref.

Comment: Deceptive use of a hashref right next to `map`, I guess clothing it in the optional codeblock curlies is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: `reverse sort { f($a) <=> f($b) } @list` could also be written as `sort { f($b) <=> f($a) } @list`

Comment: @Zaid and it could also be written `reverse sort...` which is clearer, don't you think? And the optimizer takes care of it anyway.

Comment: @hobbs : That comment was meant more for the readers than for you

Comment: Fair enough. And yeah, about the codeblock thing -- I think that `map +{ mumble => hash}, ...` is still less evil than `map { +{ mumble => hash } } ...`.

Answer (score 5):

With [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule), and [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), you can get the newest file with .pl extension, in a subtree starting from dir_path.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.12;
use strict;
use File::Find::Rule;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()->name( '*.pl' )->in( 'dir_path' );

# Note that (stat $_ )[ 9 ] yields last modified timestamp
@files = 
   map { $_->[ 0 ] }
   sort { $b->[ 1 ] <=> $a->[ 1 ] }
   map { [ $_, ( stat $_ )[ 9 ] ] } @files;

# Here is the newest file in path dir_path
say $files[ 0 ];
```

The map-sort-map chain is a typical idiom: getting timestamp is slow, so we do it only one time per file, keeping every timestamp with its file in an arrayref. Then we sort the new list using timestamp ( comparing the second element of each arrayref ), and finally we discard timestamps, keeping only filenames.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) core module.