# How to filter down a list of files to remove known duplicates

Tags: perl, duplicates

I have the following list of files:

`INV_1400524_20170412_052945.pdf
INV_1400524_20170412_063522.pdf
INV_1400524_20170412_090338.pdf
INV_1400524_20170412_092911.pdf
INV_1400971_20170502_095250.pdf
INV_1401580_20170703_100410.pdf
INV_1401880_20170804_112917.pdf
RIN_1300355_20170503_014347.pdf
RIN_1300552_20170518_111143.pdf
RIN_1300552_20170518_122055.pdf
RIN_1300688_20170627_040340.pdf
RIN_1300834_20170727_113641.pdf
RIN_1300834_20170727_154404.pdf`

which have the format:

`<Document Type>_<Document Number>_<Date>_<Time>.pdf`

As you can see, for some reason the same document number has been output multiple times. I want to ignore the duplicates and filter the list down to unique document numbers and the latest date. These documents also have a modified file timestamp that closely matches the date and time in the filename if that helps.

Using perl (I have been using File::Find::Rule) I want to reduce the list down to:

`INV_1400524_20170412_092911.pdf
INV_1400971_20170502_095250.pdf
INV_1401580_20170703_100410.pdf
INV_1401880_20170804_112917.pdf
RIN_1300355_20170503_014347.pdf
RIN_1300552_20170518_122055.pdf
RIN_1300688_20170627_040340.pdf
RIN_1300834_20170727_154404.pdf`

I have started with

```
my @pdf_files = File::Find::Rule->new
  ->in($root_dir)
   ->name( '*.pdf' )
   ->mtime (">$days_ago");
```

But looking at this answer:
[How can I find the newest .pl file in a directory and all its subdirectories using Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585145/how-can-i-find-the-newest-pl-file-in-a-directory-and-all-its-subdirectories-usi)

I think there maybe a way to use:

```
my $rule = File::Find::Rule->new;
$rule->or( $rule->new->name('INV_*.pdf')->....
$rule->or( $rule->new->name('RIN_*.pdf')->....
my @files = $rule->in($root_dir);
```

to group and filter them down. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice idiom using `grep`:

```
my %seen; 
my @files = grep { not $seen{$_}++ } @files;
```

Because you postincrement, the test is true the first time, and false all the others. You can also use regex to substring match on e.g. document ID:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

chomp(
   my @files = <DATA>
);

my %seen;
@files = grep { m/(\d+)/ and not $seen{$1}++ } @files;

print Dumper \@files;

__DATA__
INV_1400524_20170412_052945.pdf
INV_1400524_20170412_063522.pdf
INV_1400524_20170412_090338.pdf
INV_1400524_20170412_092911.pdf
INV_1400971_20170502_095250.pdf
INV_1401580_20170703_100410.pdf
INV_1401880_20170804_112917.pdf
RIN_1300355_20170503_014347.pdf
RIN_1300552_20170518_111143.pdf
RIN_1300552_20170518_122055.pdf
RIN_1300688_20170627_040340.pdf
RIN_1300834_20170727_113641.pdf
RIN_1300834_20170727_154404.pdf
```

This outputs:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'INV_1400524_20170412_052945.pdf',
          'INV_1400971_20170502_095250.pdf',
          'INV_1401580_20170703_100410.pdf',
          'INV_1401880_20170804_112917.pdf',
          'RIN_1300355_20170503_014347.pdf',
          'RIN_1300552_20170518_111143.pdf',
          'RIN_1300688_20170627_040340.pdf',
          'RIN_1300834_20170727_113641.pdf'
        ];
```

If your criteria is more compliated, then you may need to apply a sort to ensure the 'first' is filtered to the top.

There's two approaches there - either you can `sort` on the filename - and because you have an ISO date, it looks like that'll work:

```
@files = grep { m/(\d+)/ and not $seen{$1}++ } sort @files;
```

Or you can do some sort based on making a `stat` syscall (for this you'll need the full file path though, so be warned!)

```
@files = grep { m/(\d+)/ and not $seen{$1}++} sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } @files;
```

`-M` is the perl filetest that checks age of file (in days).

You could use `stat` instead though.

Comment: Thanks - will try this out. As you pointed out above, I am looking for the latest date not the earliest date.

Comment: You may need to swap `$a` and `$b` in the sort criteria. But that's all.

Comment: It actually worked to use `@files = grep { m/(\d+)/ and not $seen{$1}++ } reverse sort @files;`