# Meaning of <=> (less than, equal, greater than) in Perl?

Tags: perl, comparison, operators, comparison-operators

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328673/how-can-i-find-the-newest-created-file-in-a-directory/328911#328911), I saw the syntax `<=>`; what does this mean?  It seems to be some sort of comparison based on the context, but that's all I can gather.  Partial context:

```
sub rev_by_date { $b->[9] <=> $a->[9] }
my @sorted_files = sort rev_by_date @files;
```

Comment: Perl operators are documented in `perldoc perlop` http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that perlop page!

Comment: The documentation for your version is installed alongside Perl: `$ perldoc perltoc` You should read the entire collection at least once.

Comment: Also known as the 'starship operator'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators):

> Binary "<=>" returns -1, 0, or 1 depending on whether the left
>   argument is numerically less than, equal to, or greater than the right
>   argument. If your platform supports NaNs (not-a-numbers) as numeric
>   values, using them with "<=>" returns undef. NaN is not "<", "==",
>   ">", "<=" or ">=" anything (even NaN), so those 5 return false. NaN !=
>   NaN returns true, as does NaN != anything else. If your platform
>   doesn't support NaNs then NaN is just a string with numeric value 0.

Comment: Thank you, that link will be helpful too!